# How to extend a react component from a library

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, prototype, react-bootstrap

I want to extend the FormControl component from [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io). Importantly though, I want my extended component to *replace* the react-bootstrap component, so that importing from the react-bootstrap package actually imports my extended component.

Mostly I need to change the render method to include an absolutely-positioned counter for `input[type=text]` and `textarea` nodes, by looking at their `inputRef` prop.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Reacts core idea is composability over inheritance . So you wrap you component around the bootstrap component and use your component everywhere .

Comment: First of all, I specifically said I wanted to replace the component, not wrap it. Second of all, if I wrapped it, I would not have access to the child props inside its render.

Answer (score 1):

For extending, this should do:

```
import MyComponent from 'react-bootstrap'

class NewComponent extends MyComponent {

}
```

Pretty sure you can't overwrite an import from a package like you want though because it makes no sense to do so. Just import from the new component instead.

Why exactly do you want to overwrite the existing instead of just providing a wrapping component that inherits it?

Comment: Because I would like to write an npm package that "extends" react-bootstrap without having to import components from it directly. I get that it's a little strange to do it this way, but this is my preferred use case and I think a lot of other people's too, since it's such a simple enhancement.

Comment: You are providing a new package. Anyone that uses this new package will need to reference your wrapper and not the bootstrap one. It would be  counter-intuitive for a user to import `'react-bootstrap'` and then get your package back.